# Selenium Driver: How to find the element added after the webpage is loaded?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So the webpage has a button that after clicking will add an element to the webpage, in which I can't find using `selenium`

Some imaginary code as follows to explain the problem I experience:

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome()
#Go to my target website
d.get("https://some_website_url") #ref1
#Okay now loading of the website is done. `d` will not be updated and this is the problem!!

#Click my target button and an element with id="SecretButton" is loaded.
d.find_element_by_css_selector("#secretlyupdatethewebpage").click()

#Find #SecretButton but to no avail. 
#It can be found in the html panel of Chrome Developer Tools
#but cannot be found in the webdriver `d`, as `d` won't be 
#updated after #ref1
d.find_element_by_css_selector("#SecretButton").click()
```

How can I find that #SecretButton?

Comment: U can use an explicit wait on the visibility of the element - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: @Grasshopper In between the two clicks, I am actually on debug mode and I wait until the page has totally updated.  It turns out that the #SecretButton is on another frame so that's why I can't find the element when the frame hasn't been switched. And yes, I should add `WebDriverWait` in between the two clicks during the actual run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find and invoke `click()` on the secret button you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "SecretButton"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#SecretButton"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='SecretButton']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```